# 'unlink' is not deleting file

Tags: php, file

```
unlink("nextflights/Flight".$_POST['removeid']."/file1.jpg");
```

lets say `$_POST['removeid']` is 70,
so I should end up with
`unlink("nextflights/Flight70/file1.jpg");`

 but PHP is not deleteding the file...

Comment: This means that either your path is wrong or you have a permission issue. Both issues should be clearly pointed out in your http servers error log file. Did you look there? That always should be the first thing to do when running into an issue.

Comment: have you tried using `getcwd()` ? i also think that your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The path is relative to what is running it.

Comment: I Think i know what you mean,
The file is in public_html
and the file i want to delete is in public_html/nextflights/Flight70/file1.jpg